# Why function $f$ is concave (convex upward) $\iff\forall x,\exists\text{ vector } \boldsymbol v(x) s.t. \forall z, f(z)-f(x)\leq (z-x)\cdot v(x)$

Tags: analysis, derivatives, continuity, convex-analysis, hessian-matrix

**[Definition]** $f$  is concave (convex upward) when
$$\forall x,y\in G,\forall 0<\lambda<1, \,f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\geq \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y) $$

> Prove that
> $f:G\to\mathbb{R} \, (G\subset\mathbb{R^n} \text{ is a domain})$ is concave (convex upward) $$\iff \forall x,\exists \text{ a vector }  \boldsymbol v(x)\in \mathbb{ R}^n \, \mathrm{s.t.} \, \forall z ,\ f(z)-f(x)\leq (z-x)\cdot \boldsymbol{v}(x)$$

- $(1)$ for $f\in C^1$, it's easy to prove the theorem above and $ \boldsymbol v(x)=\nabla f(x)$,and for $f\in C^{2}$ Hessian is positive definite;
- $(2)$ $1$-dimension is easy, because
  $$\forall x\leq y\leq z, \bigg[\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\geq \frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}\Longrightarrow \hspace{5cm}$$
  $$ \hspace{3cm} \exists f'_+(x),f'_-(x), \; f(z)-f(x)\leq\min\{f'_+(x),f'_-(x)\}(z-x) \bigg]$$
- $(3)$ But for any $f$, I can only prove that in any direction $ \hat{\boldsymbol r} , f(x+\hat{ \boldsymbol r} t)-f(x)\leq C( \hat{\boldsymbol r})||\hat{\boldsymbol r}t||$ (same as $1$-dimension case), but how should I find $\boldsymbol{v}(x)$?

Comment: Hint: Consider the 2nd order or higher Taylor expansion of some function. How is the expression of concave related to derivatives?

Comment: but f is not always smooth, maby we just know $f\in C^0$, so we cannot differentiate it.

Comment: I guess I know how toprove this. just let$ v(x)=(C(e_i))$,where $e_i$ is a set of basis.

Comment: Consider subgradient.